# Filter and combine two arrays, matching two fields/columns : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

Using childcare schools - I have two arrays that I need to match on 2 columns of each array:

Attendance by Department: [date, dept, attended]

```
    0: (3) ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", 22]
    1: (3) ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", 38]
    2: (3) ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", 40]
    3: (3) ["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", 42]
    4: (3) ["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", 19]
    5: (3) ["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", 27]
    6: (3) ["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", 42]
    7: (3) ["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", 51]
```

ETC...

Expense by Department [date, dept, expense]

```
    0: (3) ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", "584.56"]
    1: (3) ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", "701.51"]
    2: (3) ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", "614.02"]
    3: (3) ["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", "442.50"]
    4: (3) ["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", "166.65"]
    5: (3) ["09-30-2019", "06_Floater", "141.37"]
    6: (3) ["09-30-2019", "07_Office", "246.91"]
    7: (3) ["09-30-2019", "08_Administration", "0.00"]
    8: (3) ["09-30-2019", "09_Director", "0.00"]
    9: (3) ["09-30-2019", "12_Kitchen", "0.00"]
    10: (3) ["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", "760.37"]
    11: (3) ["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", "756.48"]
    12: (3) ["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", "640.23"]
    13: (3) ["10-01-2019", "03_Threes", "552.66"]
```

--

I want to match Expense.date && Expense.department to Attendance.date && Attendance.department ONLY where .department appears in Attendance[]
THEN,
append Expense.expense to the matched record in Attendance

I've tried mapping, filtering, d3.js nest(), Object.assign(), ifs, $.each...

Here is the really bad last things I haven't deleted and started over from scratch - I understand it alone looks awful and not close; however, SO wanted code.

```
    let ffs = attended.map(function (x, i) {
    return {
        "date": emp[x],
        "other": emp[i][0]
    }
    }.bind(this));

let mfer = attended.map(x => Object.assign(x, emp.find(y => y[0] === x[0])));
```

Expected results: [date, department, attended, expense]

```
    0: (3) ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", 22, 584.56]
    1: (3) ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", 38, 701.51]
    2: (3) ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", 40, 613.02]
```

### Actual results: anything and everything but.

### My browser search history shows 115 relevant queries between 19:00 yesterday and present 08:30.

I believe this should be simple solution but me being in a learning state I am challenged beyond the time I should be spending on it.

-
I believe this to be the closest to what I need but everything becomes unclear when trying to apply the second filter to capture department:

### [Applying filter within a filter in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430908/applying-filter-within-a-filter-in-javascript)

some open tabs...

[Find all matching elements with in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311150/find-all-matching-elements-with-in-an-array-of-objects)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

[Javascript multiple filters array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439040/javascript-multiple-filters-array)

[merge two arrays including some fields from each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853315/merge-two-arrays-including-some-fields-from-each)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on attendance array and use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the expense for that date and department.

If expense exists, then append expense else return the same item.

```js
var attendance = [ ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", 22], ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", 38], ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", 40], ["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", 42], ["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", 19], ["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", 27], ["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", 42], ["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", 51] ];

var expenses = [ ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", "584.56"], ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", "701.51"], ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", "614.02"], ["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", "442.50"], ["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", "166.65"], ["09-30-2019", "06_Floater", "141.37"], ["09-30-2019", "07_Office", "246.91"], ["09-30-2019", "08_Administration", "0.00"], ["09-30-2019", "09_Director", "0.00"], ["09-30-2019", "12_Kitchen", "0.00"], ["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", "760.37"], ["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", "756.48"], ["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", "640.23"], ["10-01-2019", "03_Threes", "552.66"] ];

var result = attendance.map(item => {
  let expense = expenses.find(expense => expense[0] === item[0] && expense[1] === item[1]);
  if (expense) {
    return [...item, expense[2]];
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I rewarded you the point (all current 3 answers work great) because of your use in the ...Spread; It allowed me to be able to finally grasp the concept and insert ideas of Next features to add. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @nikhil Would you mind taking a stab? [NEXT PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553556/how-to-map-merge-differently-structured-objects-matched-by-date-and-departmen)

Comment: Sure @KSails, I'll take a look and reply or answer the question within next few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `Attendance` and check with `Array.prototype.find()` if there's a match in `Departments`. If we find a matching department we push the (parsed) amount into the attendance entry.

```js
const attendance = [["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", 22],["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", 38],["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", 40],["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", 42],["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", 19],["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", 27],["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", 42],["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", 51]];
const departments = [["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", "584.56"],["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", "701.51"],["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", "614.02"],["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", "442.50"],["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", "166.65"],["09-30-2019", "06_Floater", "141.37"],["09-30-2019", "07_Office", "246.91"],["09-30-2019", "08_Administration", "0.00"],["09-30-2019", "09_Director", "0.00"],["09-30-2019", "12_Kitchen", "0.00"],["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", "760.37"],["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", "756.48"],["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", "640.23"],["10-01-2019", "03_Threes", "552.66"]];


attendance.forEach(a => {
  const department = departments.find(d => a[0] === d[0] && a[1] === d[1]);
  
  if (department) {
    a.push(parseFloat(department[2]));
  }
});

console.log(attendance);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer; your answer works great. I wish I could award everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can group these elements in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by a "key". In your case, the key can be date and department. So

- create a mapping from your expenses array
- iterate through the attendance array, fetch the expense for the matching key from the grouping created above and append the expense to that array

```js
const attendance = [
  ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", 22],
  ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", 38],
  ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", 40],
  ["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", 42],
  ["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", 19],
  ["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", 27],
  ["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", 42],
  ["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", 51]
];
const expenses = [
  ["09-30-2019", "00_Infants", "584.56"],
  ["09-30-2019", "01_Ones", "701.51"],
  ["09-30-2019", "02_Twos", "614.02"],
  ["09-30-2019", "03_Threes", "442.50"],
  ["09-30-2019", "04_Fours", "166.65"],
  ["09-30-2019", "06_Floater", "141.37"],
  ["09-30-2019", "07_Office", "246.91"],
  ["09-30-2019", "08_Administration", "0.00"],
  ["09-30-2019", "09_Director", "0.00"],
  ["09-30-2019", "12_Kitchen", "0.00"],
  ["10-01-2019", "00_Infants", "760.37"],
  ["10-01-2019", "01_Ones", "756.48"],
  ["10-01-2019", "02_Twos", "640.23"],
  ["10-01-2019", "03_Threes", "552.66"]
];

const key = (date, department) => `${date};${department}`;
const expenseMap = new Map(expenses.map(([date, dept, expense]) => [key(date, dept), expense]));

attendance.forEach(a => a.push(expenseMap.get(key(a[0], a[1]))));
console.log(attendance)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tested all 3 current answers and they all work. I wish I could reward everyone. Would you tell me what search terms I can use to understand `${date};${department}`; ?... It's joining 2 keys but I want to read more. thank you.

Comment: @KSails that fine :) You can look for "template literals" to understand what that syntax means: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you! On my unofficial list of things to learn effectively.