# How to map / merge differently structured objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

SUMMARY:

I need to insert the values from `Students` into the `Employees` corresponding values so that `Students` value appears in the same array as `Employees['avg_rate' and 'expense']`;

The new or modified object array should be matched on Dates and Department (ex. 00_Infants) THEN excluding departments that are not present in both Students and Employees.

Thank you.

---

```
// "Students" aka "attendance values by department"
Object
    0:
        00_Infants: 30
        01_Ones: 35
        02_Twos: 39
        03_Threes: 38
        04_Fours: 21
        05_School_Age: 0
        key: "10-10-2019"
        __proto__: Object
    1: {key: "10-11-2019", 00_Infants: 33, 01_Ones: 35, 02_Twos: 36, …}
    2: {key: "10-14-2019", 00_Infants: 30, 01_Ones: 33, 02_Twos: 40, …}
```

---

```
// "employees"
Array(12)
    0:
        key: "10-10-2019"
        values: Array(11)
            0:
                key: "00_Infants"
                value:
                    avg_rate: 13.236842105263158
                    expense: 764.1350000000001
                    __proto__: Object
                    __proto__: Object
            1: {key: "01_Ones", value: {…}}
            2: {key: "02_Twos", value: {…}}
            3: {key: "03_Threes", value: {…}}
            4: {key: "04_Fours", value: {…}}
            5: {key: "06_Floater", value: {…}}
            6: {key: "07_Office", value: {…}}
            7: {key: "08_Administration", value: {…}}
            8: {key: "09_Director", value: {…}}
            9: {key: "12_Kitchen", value: {…}}
            10: {key: "13_Unknown", value: {…}}
            length: 11
            __proto__: Array(0)
            __proto__: Object
    1: {key: "10-11-2019", values: Array(10)}
    2: {key: "10-14-2019", values: Array(9)}
```

---

DESIRED RESULT:

```
{
    Date:"10-09-2019"{
        00_Infants: {
            avg_rate:     13.39,
            expense:     776.58,
            attendance:   28
        },
        01_Ones: {
            avg_rate:     13.31,
            expense:     716.58,
            attendance:   33
        },
},        
{   // for each date
    Date:"10-10-2019"{ 
    // for each department ^
    }
}
```

Comment: please add what you like to calculate. with an example and the result. btw, why not use an array of counting properties?

Comment: @NinaScholz Hi Nina - thanks for the comment. "Why not use an array of counting properties?" --- my lack of knowledge and skill; I expect I'm making this much more difficult than it should be; however, I'm stuck.

Comment: @KSails - You added `attendance: 28` in desired result, how did you get that value? By adding `students` array item values? Also, can you post example JSON data of `students` and `employees`? It is not clear whether they are arrays or objects. I'm suspecting they are arrays but want to confirm.

Comment: @Nikhil - thank you for checking it out.  `attendance: 28`  ... correct by adding `students` value into the "employees" array. Updated w/ JSON data of `students` and `employees`

Comment: please perform a `JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4)` and get the formatted data for the question. the copy of a console view is virtual not usable because of the redundant informationa nd further informations like indices. plase add the wanted result as well as the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) can be used to get values of `students` object and [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be used to iterate on these values.
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method can be used to find the employee in `employees` array with matching date.
- Then for each value in student's object item, `find()` can be used to find the department in employee object and `attendance` property with appropriate value can be added.

**Code:**

```
Object.values(students).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  let employee = employees.find(obj => obj.key === value.key);

  if (employee) {
    Object.entries(value).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (k !== "key") {
        let dept = employee.values.find(dept => dept.key === k);

        if (dept) {
          dept.value.attendance = v;
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil - I was able to solve this problem with your solution.